# Python zip a sub folder and not the entire folder path

Tags: python, subdirectory, zip

I have a program to zip all the contents in a folder. I did not write this code but I found it somewhere online and I am using it. I intend to zip a folder for example say, C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/ . I want to zip folder3 and all its contents in a file say folder3.zip. With the below code, once i zip it, the contents of folder3.zip wil be folder1/folder2/folder3/and files. I do not want the entire path to be zipped and i only want the subfolder im interested to zip (folder3 in this case). I tried some os.chdir etc, but no luck.

```
def makeArchive(fileList, archive):
    """
    'fileList' is a list of file names - full path each name
    'archive' is the file name for the archive with a full path
    """
    try:
        a = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        for f in fileList:
            print "archiving file %s" % (f)
            a.write(f)
        a.close()
        return True
    except: return False 

def dirEntries(dir_name, subdir, *args):
    # Creates a list of all files in the folder
    '''Return a list of file names found in directory 'dir_name'
    If 'subdir' is True, recursively access subdirectories under 'dir_name'.
    Additional arguments, if any, are file extensions to match filenames. Matched
        file names are added to the list.
    If there are no additional arguments, all files found in the directory are
        added to the list.
    Example usage: fileList = dirEntries(r'H:\TEMP', False, 'txt', 'py')
        Only files with 'txt' and 'py' extensions will be added to the list.
    Example usage: fileList = dirEntries(r'H:\TEMP', True)
        All files and all the files in subdirectories under H:\TEMP will be added
        to the list. '''

    fileList = []
    for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
        dirfile = os.path.join(dir_name, file)
        if os.path.isfile(dirfile):
            if not args:
                fileList.append(dirfile)
            else:
                if os.path.splitext(dirfile)[1][1:] in args:
                    fileList.append(dirfile)
            # recursively access file names in subdirectories
        elif os.path.isdir(dirfile) and subdir:
            print "Accessing directory:", dirfile
            fileList.extend(dirEntries(dirfile, subdir, *args))
    return fileList
```

You can call this by `makeArchive(dirEntries(folder, True), zipname)`.

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem? I am uing windows OS annd python 25, i know in python 2.7 there is shutil make_archive which helps but since i am working on 2.5 i need another solution :-/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll have to give an `arcname` argument to [`ZipFile.write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) that uses a relative path. Do this by giving the root path to remove to `makeArchive()`:

```
def makeArchive(fileList, archive, root):
    """
    'fileList' is a list of file names - full path each name
    'archive' is the file name for the archive with a full path
    """
    a = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for f in fileList:
        print "archiving file %s" % (f)
        a.write(f, os.path.relpath(f, root))
    a.close()
```

and call this with:

```
makeArchive(dirEntries(folder, True), zipname, folder)
```

I've removed the blanket `try:`, `except:`; there is no use for that here and only serves to hide problems you want to know about.

The [`os.path.relpath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) function returns a path relative to `root`, effectively removing that root path from the archive entry.

On python 2.5, the `relpath` function is not available; for this specific usecase the following replacement would work:

```
def relpath(filename, root):
    return filename[len(root):].lstrip(os.path.sep).lstrip(os.path.altsep)
```

and use:

```
a.write(f, relpath(f, root))
```

Note that the above `relpath()` function only works for your specific case where `filepath` is guaranteed to start with `root`; on Windows the general case for `relpath()` is a lot more complex. You really want to upgrade to Python 2.6 or newer if at all possible.

Comment: I tried this method, but since I am using 2.5 i dont think i can use relpath. I got this message:   File "C:\Python25\example\fullzipnew.py", line 14, in makeArchive
    a.write(f, os.path.relpath(f, root))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'relpath'

Comment: @kraxter: indeed, `os.path.relpath()` was added in 2.6. Why not upgrade your python version? 2.5 is very old by now.

Comment: I know :-/ but for now i am working on 2.5 and do you think there is any other work around? :'(

Comment: @kraxter: I've updated my answer to provide a work-around for your specific case.

Comment: Thank you for the work around. It works just they way I wanted it to. I know I need to upgrade from 2.5. Soon! :)

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

[ZipFile.write](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write) has an optional argument `arcname`. Use this to remove parts of the path.

You could change your method to be:

```
def makeArchive(fileList, archive, path_prefix=None):
    """
    'fileList' is a list of file names - full path each name
    'archive' is the file name for the archive with a full path
    """
    try:
        a = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        for f in fileList:
            print "archiving file %s" % (f)
            if path_prefix is None:
                a.write(f)
            else:
                a.write(f, f[len(path_prefix):] if f.startswith(path_prefix) else f)
        a.close()
        return True
    except: return False
```

Martijn's approach using os.path is much more elegant, though.

Comment: Now you can end up with a path separator at the start of `arcname` if `path_prefix` doesn't end with a slash..

Comment: I know - therefore I recommended your approach.

Comment: I've tried this method and this works the same way too. Thanks!